# Room Database сложный фильтр для выборки

Tags: java, android, android-room, фильтр

Всем привет!
Ищу помощь у тех, кто сталкивался с подобной задачей или у тех, кто знает, как ее решить.

Суть задачи: я пишу приложение для себя наподобие записной книжки, в которой хочу хранить своих клиентов (номера телефонов, адреса и прочее). Всю информацию храню в базе данных *SQLite* при помощи *Room Database*. 
Так вот предположим, что у меня уже есть данные в этой таблице с клиентами и я хотел бы сделать к ним фильтр -- это будет диалоговое окно с двумя *Spinner*:

1. *Один Spinner* содержит варианты выборки: *все клиенты, за сегодня, за неделю, за месяц*
2. *Второй Spinner* содержит варианты сортировки: *по имени, по дате добавления, срочные, и не срочные*

Теперь самое главное! Как в *Dao* можно прописать такой метод, который бы фильтровал по таким параметрам? Мне в голову приходила мысль создавать много методов для каждого варианта сортировки и выборки, но я понимаю что это тот еще костыль. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Сам задавался таким вопросом и другого решения я пока-что не нашёл. Была мысля пробовать передавать эти параметры через параметры метода, например:

```
@Query("SELEC * FROM contact :where :orderBy")
fun getListContacts(where: String = "", orderBy: String = "") : List<Contact>

where = "WHERE date > время от нуля за сегодня"
orderBy = "ORDER BY name ASC"
```

И так далее, но метод ещё не испытан, времени не было потестить, возможно даже не рабочий или где-то ошибся, писал на коленке. Как проверите отпишитесь.

Ну и второй составалять на каждую выборку по первому пункту свой запрос, а сортировать уже по месту.

P.S. вот эта конструкция: where: `String = ""` - это из Kotlin-а, позволяющая не задавать параметры при вызове функции.